# Is this disk read speed to be expected (Amazon EBS)?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, amazon-web-services, hard-drive

our Amazon EBS backed instance has slowed down considerably (maybe shifted physical host?).

I've checked the instance using top and the CPU use is very low when the process is activated (like 1%).  Using iotop I have monitored the disk read speed of postgresql.  When there is only one postgresql thread running it's reporting about a 5M/s read speed.  Is this rather slow or is this in the parameters of usual disk read speeds?

Thanks

Comment: This question would fit much better on a different stackexchange site, http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5MB/s its more or less the typical for one single hard drive. I mean sequential accesses of course. If you have only one hard disk then your CPU its fine since one hard disk its not enough to stress out your CPU probably, if you are not reaching any more speed than that even with constant queries then your hard disk its the bottleneck.